# Get value from invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

This code returns the value of the registry from a remote machine. How to format output as a table with two columns containing information such as ComputerName and RegistryValue. Note: RunspaceId doesn't not contain RegistryValue information.

```
$comps = "smzmi0020d", "smzmi0025d"
$block = { (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate' -name susclientid).susclientid }

PS C:\Windows\system32> invoke-command $comps -ScriptBlock $block | select susclientID, PSComputername

susclientID PSComputerName
----------- --------------
            smzmi0020d
            smzmi0025d

PS C:\Windows\system32> invoke-command $comps -ScriptBlock $block | select *

PSComputerName RunspaceId                           Length
-------------- ----------                           ------
smzmi0020d     1be1be2f-7e57-4833-81a0-6182c5ac3672     36
smzmi0025d     10e067da-06a0-4962-ae89-898aef9fe81c     36
```

Comment: build a `[PSCustomObject]` in your scriptblock that has the desired properties. then send that out to be returned to your `Invoke-Command` call.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it seems there was another solution. But I'm interested in seeing yours

Comment: the solution by `Ivan Mirchev` uses `Select-Object` to build a PSObject from each item from the returned data. my variant would build the object on the remote system and return that. not really any different - location and minor structural details. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not being able to reproduce in my environment, but you may try something like:

```
$Comps = "smzmi0020d", "smzmi0025d"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Comps -ScriptBlock {(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate' -name susclientid)} | Select-Object -Property SusClientID, PSComputerName
```

Note: `Foreach-Object` processes the objects sequentially, while `Invoke-Command` does that in parallel (32 computers simultaneously by default). Therefore it should be much faster!

`Invoke-Command` also returuns the parameter `PSComputerName` which holds the name of the computer retunrning the output, so with `Select-Object` at the end you should be just fine. Eventually you may pipe the output to `| Format-Table -AutoSize`.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to include the output. Select SusClientID doesn't work for me. It shows an empty column.

Comment: Code edited! you do not need to address the property inside (.susclientID).

Answer (score 0):

The block only returns a string because of `.susclientid`, so `| select susclientID` doesn't make sense.  You can do it this way too and get a susclientid property, but you also get the runspaceid property as usual.

```
$block = { Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate | 
  select susclientid }
```